# JavaScript String Handling

Tags: javascript, php, string

I am passing a php value to javascript using onclick method, so it kind of looks like this

```
onclick="(method('<?php echo $variable; ?>'))"
```

But my problem is one of my values are "Ike's" , it contains a single qoute, which breaks the code. Any way in javascript to complete consider a passed parameter as a string,not anything else?
thanks

Comment: question should be how to escape quotes in php. The html has to be valid first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be more about PHP than Javascript, based on the code snippet you provided.  Basically, you might want to escape the apostrophes with a backslash character.

`onclick="(method('<?php echo $variable; ?>'))"`

would then become something like this perhaps:

`onclick="(method('<?php echo addslashes($variable); ?>'))"`

... and please remove the parenthesis you have surrounding the onclick event, like so:

`onclick="method('<?php echo addslashes($variable); ?>')"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the string from PHP before passing it to Javascript. For example:

```
onclick="(method('<?php echo addslashes($variable); >'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well. I would prefer to use:

```
<div id="the_php_output">
<?php echo $variable; ?>
</div>

<input onclick="js_method()">
<script>
function js_method(){
  $("#the_php_output").html();
}
</script>
```